# Javascript replace not working

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm working on javascript and I have some problem with javascript replace function.
Here is my code:

```
var jpgPath ="../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm201000135.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001352.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001353.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001354.jpg@../Publish       
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001355.jpg@../Publish    
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001356.jpg@../Publish   
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001357.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001358.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001359.jpg@../Publish  
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013510.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013511.jpg@../Publish
/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013512.jpg";

jpgPath = jpgPath.replace("..", "../..");
```

but it's not replacing all the occurrence of ".." with "../..", it's replacing the first match and after that it ignore other matches.

Answer (score 7):

Pass a regex with global flag as first param

```
jpgPath = jpgPath.replace(/\.\./g, "../..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
jpgPath = jpgPath.replace(/../g, ”../..”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `jpgPath = jpgPath.replace(/\.\./g, "../..");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'll need to use the regex and the `g` (global) operator:

```
// because . is a special character in regex, you need to escape it
jpgPath = jpgPath.replace(/\.\./g, "../..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var jpgPath ="../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm201000135.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001352.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001353.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001354.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001355.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001356.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001357.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001358.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm2010001359.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013510.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013511.jpg@../Publish/Pdf/Publish_27Jul2011_04-47-09_PM/adfm20100013512.jpg";

jpgPath = jpgPath.replace(/\.\./g, "../..");

console.log(jpgPath );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8Wp8/